# Can't find BlackPawnTextureBuilder for AndEngine

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, andengine

I'm trying to implement [this Parallax Background here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/features/scrollable-parallax-background-t5390.html) but I cannot find the BlackPawnTextureBuilder file anywhere! I don't even have a org.anddev package to import. I have a feeling it has something to do with a missing OpenGL library, but I could be wrong.

I also found [this class](https://github.com/sebnil/Sketchy-Truck/blob/master/andengine/src/org/anddev/andengine/opengl/texture/atlas/buildable/builder/BlackPawnTextureBuilder.java) online that I tried to use but it throws loads of errors.

In my Parallax Background scene, I have no errors except for this part:

```
 try {
             texture.build(new BlackPawnTextureBuilder(0));
     } catch (TextureAtlasSourcePackingException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

which throws a `BlackPawnTextureBuilder cannot be resolved to a type` and `TextureAtlasSourcePackingException cannot be resolved to a type` errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of AndEngine from source ?

Comment: I thought so! How can I tell?

Comment: I wrote this tutorial for setting AndEngine GLES2.0 on Eclipse long time ago, it should be similar if you are using Android Studios [make sure you pick GLES2.0-AnchorCenter branch, my tutorial is outdated] http://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/setting-up-andengine-gles2-0/

Comment: It set up my project months ago though. Is there a way I can check if my current project uses the correct version?

Comment: how did you set it up ? are you using Eclipse or Android Studio ? did you set it up from Github or did you download a jar file ?

Comment: I'm using eclipse and I pulled it from GitHub using the eclipse git plugin.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this explain your downvote please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that BlackPawnTextureBuilder is deprecated [can't find it] try using [BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/720897f99d2c56ba357e8fe361454bd8d88c37ed/src/org/andengine/opengl/texture/atlas/buildable/builder/BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder.java)